# Package management in Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio, package

This may be a stupid question, but so, i have a simple app:
http://tinypic.com/r/2ekolxd/8

Let's say i want to create a package called "SocialNetworks", where i need to implement some features like posting in social networks etc. So, i create a package, but i'd like to see it in the following way: http://tinypic.com/r/sy0ck1/8

But instead whenever i create a new package, it just renames main package : http://tinypic.com/r/zboup/8

How to avoid this?

P.S. Sorry, i can't post images :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ flattens the packages by default if the package does not contain anything except other packages. You can disable this behavior by clicking on the settings icon in Project view and unchecking *Compact Empty Middle Packages*.

[image]